# Init 2d array during runtime?

Tags: objective-c

So when I create a reference to an 2d array i have to specify its size? But during runtime I need to decide its size, or change its size? How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of NSArray use NSMutableArray.
With that type you can change the size afterwards and add more objects later during runtime.

Comment: Its a 2d array taken from c as you cannot declare a 2d as such in objective c -.-